# CompleteableFuture throws IOException when trying to read from http file download InputStream

Tags: java, amazon-s3, inputstream, completable-future

So I'm struggling to find the proper way to stream a file download into an s3 bucket without having to write it to disk or keep it all in memory. I have a solution working where I generate the InputStream from a HttpUrlConnection object then pass it to the s3 putObject call like so:

```
HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) resourceUrl.openConnection();
httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
httpConn.connect();
int contentLength = httpConn.getContentLength();
try (InputStream is = httpConn.getInputStream()) {
    ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
    objectMetadata.setContentLength(contentLength);
    PutObjectRequest req = new PutObjectRequest(bucketname,url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/")),is,objectMetadata);
    s3client.putObject(req);
}
```

This works except that it is blocking, so when you submit the url with the resource to pull down it churns away server side but takes so long to complete (the files are 500 mb+) that the POST request ends in a 500 even though it works successfully.

So I tired moving over to CompletableFuture objects to try and make it run in its own thread. I've been trying to cobble the code together from different sources I've found online and came to this:

```
try (InputStream is = httpConn.getInputStream()) {
ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
objectMetadata.setContentLength(contentLength);
PutObjectRequest req = new PutObjectRequest(bucketname,url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/")),is,objectMetadata);
CompletableFuture<PutObjectResult> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->
    s3client.putObject(req), Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1));
future.whenComplete((resp, err) -> {
    try {
    if (resp != null) {
        System.out.println(resp);
    } else {
        // Handle error
        err.printStackTrace();
    }
    } finally {
        // Lets the application shut down. Only close the client when you are completely done with it.
        s3client.shutdown();
    }
});
...
```

The code above causes the following stack trace:

> java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: stream is closed
>           at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:273)
>           ...
>   Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: stream is closed
>           at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1114)
>           at
>   **appback.MyResource.lambda$processNewMachine$0(MyResource.java:93)**
>           ... 7 more
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: stream is closed
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.ensureOpen(HttpURLConnection.java:3348)
>   ... 18 more

Where line 93 is the call to **s3client.putObject(req)**

I've based to code off this snippet from an opensource project I found while googling around

```
    @Override
public CompletableFuture<PutObjectResult> putObject(String bucketName, String key, InputStream inputStream,
        int length) {
    ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
    objectMetadata.setContentLength(length);
    ...
    PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, key, inputStream, objectMetadata);
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> s3Client.putObject(putObjectRequest), executorService);
}
```

The fact that they're almost identical makes me think I have a wrong assumption about how InputStreams can be passed to CompletableFuture calls. Please let me know if you have any insights into how to fix this problem. Thank you!

Comment: The problem looks to be your using try-with-resources on an InputStream, but you read from the stream in a different thread. So you close the stream when you leave the try with resources block, but the thread is still churning and trying to read from it.

Comment: So I don't know if it changes your thoughts but the second snippet of code is in the try block, I probably should have included that, I am editing the question now.

Comment: You're doing the same thing -- creating the stream in the current thread and within the try-with-resources, but then handling it in a different one. Same problem, same solutions as noted in the duplicates.

Comment: Oh, no I see what you mean. So I need to open the resource in the Completable block

Comment: Taking it out of the try block worked so you can put it in an answer if you want and I'll check it.

Comment: Nah -- this is a duplicate of the questions above and so should be closed as one. I'm glad though that you've got things straightened out.